# Css animation for responsive block

Tags: css, animation, responsive

I'm constantly adding new blocks to the stage. All blocks have style `float:left` so they stick to each others side. The `width` property is defined by `media`, like so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
   .block { width: 100%; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
   .block { width: calc(100% / 2); }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .block { width: calc(100% / 3); }
}
```

The key feature is that blocks are covering the whole window width.

The problem is that I don't like that the new blocks are added instantly pushing back all the previous ones. I know how to animate the constant width, but in this case I'm dealing with variable width (in %), that depends on window size.

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: What about something like `.block{ transition: width 1s }` outside the queries?

Comment: What @MaximillianLaumeister suggested should work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, block still appends with width defined in `media`.

Comment: Can you post enough ([mcve]) code that demonstrates what you're doing, and reproduces the problem you're experiencing? That way we can produce examples that address your specific problem and you can explain what you're seeing with reference to what we're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see now is to add `resize` listener and controlls everything using js...